# Tensorboard displaying only 8 nodes for Embedding layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

[image]I tried to visualize the graph of a network with an input Embedding layer with 100 as output
dims using gloVe.100d. However, tensorboard states that only 8 nodes is present in the Embedding layer.

```
def lstm_model():
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=10000, output_dim=100, 
                              embeddings_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Constant(value=embeddings_matrix)),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=16, return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=8, return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=1),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')])

return model
```

Comment: Can you provide some more information about your problem? Maybe source codes and how does the graph look like in your Tensorboard?

Comment: @MinhNguyen please see edits

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this, but I think you can check the batch size that you use for your model since the output of the embedding layer is correlated to batch size. Also, can you click on the blocks in Tensorboard to see more details of each component (e.g. embedding block)?